# Form to swap 2 objects in database with Django

Tags: python, django

I'm new to django and I've been developing a simple application for the past month or so, but I have a problem, something I did not manage to do.
I have a simple model called WeeklyPlaylist (from my models.py):

```
class WeeklyPlaylist(models.Model):
    total_num_entries_in_playlist = 8
    get_pos_choices = get_integer_choices(1, total_num_entries_in_playlist)
    sched = models.ForeignKey(Schedule)
    week = models.IntegerField(choices=get_integer_choices(1, 52))
    position = models.IntegerField(choices=get_pos_choices)
```

where 'position' simply indicates the position of a video in a playlist.
I'd like to provide the admin with the ability to swap the position of one video in a playlist with another video in that same playlist, through the change/update form of the model above (from my admin.py):

```
class WeeklyPlaylistAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    (...)
    readonly_fields = ('position',)
    form = WeeklyPlaylistAdminForm

    def get_changelist_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        return WeeklyPlaylistAdminForm
```

and I'm defining my own form for this object (still from admin.py):

```
class WeeklyPlaylistAdminForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = WeeklyPlaylist
        fields = ('position',)

    swap_with_position = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.Select(choices=WeeklyPlaylist.get_pos_choices))

    def clean_swap_with_position(self):
        swap_with_position = self.cleaned_data['swap_with_position']
        instance = getattr(self, 'instance', None)
        if instance and instance.id and swap_with_position == self.instance.position:
            raise forms.ValidationError("You must specify a different position than the actual one.")

        # select the database obj to swap position with
        other = WeeklyPlaylist.objects.filter(sched__screen__name=self.instance.sched.screen.name, sched__year__exact=self.instance.sched.year, week=self.instance.week, position=swap_with_position)
        if other.count() != 1:
            raise forms.ValidationError("The desired position does not correspond to any existing WeeklyPlaylist entry.")

        return swap_with_position
```

What I had in my mind basically was to provide an extra 'select' html tag to the admin in the change/update form of the WeeklyPlaylist model where he could enter the new position in the playlist for the current video, with the necessary checks in the associated clean_ method to make sure the desired playlist position is valid.
So far so good. Now, my problem is the following: when the admin clicks on the 'save' button, how can I simultaneously save the modified object, and the one it is exchanging its position with? I've tried doing this in the save() method of the form, using the following code:

```
def save(self, commit=True, *args, **kwargs):
    m = super(WeeklyPlaylistAdminForm, self).save(commit=False, *args, **kwargs)
    cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
    swap_with_position = cleaned_data.get("swap_with_position")
    if commit:
        # select the database obj to swap position with
        other = WeeklyPlaylist.objects.get(sched__screen__name=m.sched.screen.name, sched__year__exact=m.sched.year, week=m.week, position=swap_with_position)
        m.position, other.position = other.position, m.position
        m.save()
        other.save()
    return m
```

That seems perfectly fine, except that for some reason, commit is always false, even though 'm' is saved after the operation is finished, which is something I don't understand. But as a consequence, other.save() is never called, and if I remove the if statement checking the value of commit, I won't be able to do a save(commit=False) on the WeeklyPlaylistAdminForm objects, which can be annoying...
So, any suggestions to help me?
Many thanks in advance!
Cheers!
Adrien

Comment: Can you try removing the commit kwarg in your .save() signature and doing `commit = kwargs.get("commit", True)` instead? Just trying to rule out the Django admin internals passing a falsy 1st argument that's getting assigned to the commit kwarg. I don't think that happens, but it's something to rule out before going deeper.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, AdamKG, I did as you said but the result is the same and commit is still set to False...

Answer (score 1):

When I've done things similar to this in Django I haven't implemented models that are specifically swapping with another category but that they re-sort the list; so moving element with order 5 to order 0 would shift all the previous elements with order in the range from 0 to 4 up, but swapping with a specifically ordered element should be much easier.

I would store the previous position of your model before any modifications take place and detect if it has changed in the save method before the saving is actually done. If it has changed then I would save the current model then do a lookup for the model that did have that position and that doesn't have the current position and do an update on that one to correct the position; hopefully the following code should help demonstrate what I mean:

```
class WeeklyPlaylist(models.Model):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(WeeklyPlaylist, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self._position = int(self.position)

  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(WeeklyPlaylist, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    # position has changed, so change the position of the element that held the new position now held by this element
    if int(self.position) != self._position:
      WeeklyPlaylist.objects.exclude(pk=self.pk).filter(
        position=self.position
      ).update(position=self._position)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Dominic, I guess it should work, but I'm a bit concerned with concurrency issues: what would happen in case 2 users users try and change the position of the same object at the same time?